# Short circuit protection

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, short-circuit

I have built an AC/AC cuk converter for an assignment I am doing. It works as such, I provide 50V AC in and I get an adjustable voltage out from 0V to 50V AC, depending on the duty cycle of the PWM that I gate to the MOSFETs. It is designed to supply a max of 1A rms to the load. I have included a schematic below, drive circuit as not been shown.
[image: IMG]

It works extacly as I have explained. However, I would like to incorporate some sort of rudementry simple short circuit protection.

Any ideas would help, thanks.

Comment: How about a fuse?

Comment: I thought of that, but would it be sufficient?

Comment: Perhaps I may have foolishly included 'rudementry' & 'simple' into the question. Are there any ICs that would deal with short circuits? or perhaps a low circuit breaker?

Comment: Is your goal to protect your components, or just to provide information that something bad may be about to happen? Should it be recoverable? Automatically? Manually but electronically (i.e. press a button rather than replace a fuse)? Etc.

Comment: Protecting the components would be my primary goal. I would also prefer it to be recoverable in a manual sense (like press a button or turning it off/on..)